# SQL Query Rewrite - Help Needed (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

Need help in re-writing the below SQL. The Query works fine for smaller database below 400 GB, but spends too much time for larger database above 600 GB.

Oracle - 11.2.0.4

Database - Oracle

```
  SELECT i.ITEM_ID,
         i.ITEM_TYPE,
         i.START_DATETIME,
         i.END_DATETIME,
         MAX (CASE WHEN ip.PROPERTY_TYPE = 'NAME' THEN ip.PROPERTY_STRING END)
            AS FIELD_NAME,
         MAX (CASE WHEN ip.PROPERTY_TYPE = 'STATE' THEN ip.PROPERTY_STRING END)
            AS FIELD_STATE,
         CL_STATE.CODE_TEXT AS STATE_TEXT,
         MAX (
            CASE WHEN ip.PROPERTY_TYPE = 'COUNTY' THEN ip.PROPERTY_STRING END)
            AS FIELD_COUNTY,
         CL_COUNTY.CODE_TEXT AS COUNTY_TEXT
    FROM ITEM i
         INNER JOIN DATE_INFO DI
            ON DI.DATETIME = TRUNC (SYSDATE) AND DI.DATE_TYPE = 'D'
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_PROPERTY ip ON (i.ITEM_ID = ip.ITEM_ID)


         LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_PROPERTY ip_STATE
            ON     ip_STATE.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
               AND ip_STATE.START_DATETIME <= DI.DATETIME
               AND ip_STATE.END_DATETIME > DI.DATETIME
               AND ip_STATE.PROPERTY_TYPE = 'STATE'
         LEFT OUTER JOIN CODE_LIST CL_STATE
            ON     CL_STATE.CODE = ip_STATE.PROPERTY_STRING
               AND CL_STATE.LIST_TYPE = 'STATE'
               AND CL_STATE.CULTURE = 'en-US'



         LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_PROPERTY ip_COUNTY
            ON     ip_COUNTY.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
               AND ip_COUNTY.START_DATETIME <= DI.DATETIME
               AND ip_COUNTY.END_DATETIME > DI.DATETIME
               AND ip_COUNTY.PROPERTY_TYPE = 'COUNTY'
         LEFT OUTER JOIN CODE_LIST CL_COUNTY
            ON     CL_COUNTY.CODE = ip_COUNTY.PROPERTY_STRING
               AND CL_COUNTY.LIST_TYPE = 'COUNTY'
               AND CL_COUNTY.CULTURE = 'en-US'



   WHERE     i.START_DATETIME <= DI.DATETIME
         AND i.END_DATETIME > DI.DATETIME
         AND ip.START_DATETIME <= DI.DATETIME
         AND ip.END_DATETIME > DI.DATETIME
         AND i.ITEM_TYPE LIKE 'FIELD'
GROUP BY i.ITEM_ID,
         i.ITEM_TYPE,
         i.START_DATETIME,
         i.END_DATETIME,
         CL_STATE.CODE_TEXT,
         CL_COUNTY.CODE_TEXT
```

Explain Plan

```
Plan hash value: 792208276

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                      |  9354 |  5161K|       | 11252   (1)| 00:02:16 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                      |                      |  9354 |  5161K|  5360K| 11252   (1)| 00:02:16 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                      |  9354 |  5161K|       | 10132   (1)| 00:02:02 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                | CODE_LIST            |  5328 |   353K|       |   120   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER            |                      |  9354 |  4539K|       | 10012   (1)| 00:02:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | CODE_LIST            |   115 |  7820 |       |    25   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN               | CODE_LIST_CUSTOM     |   115 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |     HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                      |  9354 |  3918K|  2832K|  9987   (1)| 00:02:00 |
|*  8 |      HASH JOIN OUTER                |                      |  7916 |  2736K|       |  5357   (1)| 00:01:05 |
|   9 |       VIEW                          |                      |  6698 |  1824K|       |  1017   (0)| 00:00:13 |
|  10 |        NESTED LOOPS                 |                      |  6698 |   941K|       |  1017   (0)| 00:00:13 |
|  11 |         NESTED LOOPS                |                      |   482 | 33258 |       |    53   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_DATE_INFO         |     1 |    10 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ITEM                 |   482 | 28438 |       |    52   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IX_ITEM_ITEM_TYPE_DT |   482 |       |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN            | IX_ITEM_PROPERTY4    |    14 |  1050 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | IX_ITEM_PROPERTY4    | 36913 |  2703K|       |  4340   (1)| 00:00:53 |
|* 17 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | IX_ITEM_PROPERTY4    | 36866 |  2700K|       |  4340   (1)| 00:00:53 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("CL_COUNTY"."CODE"(+)="IP_COUNTY"."PROPERTY_STRING")
   3 - filter("CL_COUNTY"."LIST_TYPE"(+)='COUNTY' AND "CL_COUNTY"."CULTURE"(+)='en-US')
   4 - access("CL_STATE"."CODE"(+)="IP_STATE"."PROPERTY_STRING")
   6 - access("CL_STATE"."LIST_TYPE"(+)='STATE' AND "CL_STATE"."CULTURE"(+)='en-US')
   7 - access("IP_COUNTY"."ITEM_ID"(+)="from$_subquery$_005"."QCSJ_C000000000500000")
       filter("IP_COUNTY"."END_DATETIME"(+)>"from$_subquery$_005"."DATETIME" AND 
              "IP_COUNTY"."START_DATETIME"(+)<="from$_subquery$_005"."DATETIME")
   8 - access("IP_STATE"."ITEM_ID"(+)="I"."ITEM_ID")
       filter("IP_STATE"."END_DATETIME"(+)>"DI"."DATETIME" AND 
              "IP_STATE"."START_DATETIME"(+)<="DI"."DATETIME")
  12 - access("DI"."DATETIME"=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "DI"."DATE_TYPE"='D')
  14 - access("I"."ITEM_TYPE"='FIELD' AND "I"."END_DATETIME">TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "I"."START_DATETIME"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
       filter("I"."END_DATETIME">TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "I"."START_DATETIME"<="DI"."DATETIME" AND 
              "I"."END_DATETIME">"DI"."DATETIME")
  15 - access("I"."ITEM_ID"="IP"."ITEM_ID" AND "IP"."END_DATETIME">TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "IP"."START_DATETIME"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
       filter("IP"."END_DATETIME">TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "IP"."START_DATETIME"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "IP"."START_DATETIME"<="DI"."DATETIME" AND "IP"."END_DATETIME">"DI"."DATETIME")
  16 - filter("IP_STATE"."PROPERTY_TYPE"(+)='STATE')
  17 - filter("IP_COUNTY"."PROPERTY_TYPE"(+)='COUNTY')
```

Explain Plan -

```
Plan
1 One or more rows were retrieved using index USAVM.AK_CODE_LIST .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
2 Rows from table USAVM.CODE_LIST  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
3 Rows were retrieved using the unique index USAVM.PK_DATE_INFO .
4 One or more rows were retrieved using index USAVM.IX_ITEM_ITEM_TYPE_DT .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
5 Rows from table USAVM.ITEM  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
6 For each row retrieved by step 3, the operation in step 5 was performed to find a matching row.
7 One or more rows were retrieved using index USAVM.IX_ITEM_PROPERTY4 .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
8 For each row retrieved by step 6, the operation in step 7 was performed to find a matching row.
9 A view definition was processed, either from a stored view SYS.  or as defined by steps 8.
10 Rows were retrieved by performing a fast read of all index records in USAVM.IX_ITEM_PROPERTY4 .
11 Rows from step 9 which matched rows from step 10 were returned (hash join).
12 The result sets from steps 2, 11 were joined (hash).
13 HASH GROUP BY
14 Rows were returned by the SELECT statement.
```

Comment: I'd start by making `LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_PROPERTY ip ` an `INNER JOIN` since this part of the where clause `ip.START_DATETIME <= DI.DATETIME` makes an inner join anyway

Comment: Still the CODE_LIST Table is joined multiple times. Is there anyway to avoid it or a better way to rewrite the query ?

Comment: Is the size of these tables proportional to the overall size of the database - saying one is 400G and the other 600G doesn't mean much if these tables are the same size in each. Is the plan in the 'fast' database the same as in the 'slow' one, and do you a reason to think it's sub-optimal - do you know something about the data that Oracle seems to not be taking into account from its stats?

Comment: The size mentioned was for the Databaase (my bad. missed that part). The response of the the query is getting slower and slower day by day has the database and tables (Business) grows. Before there were multiple LEFT OUTER JOINS, which i was able to modify it to MAX(CASE), but still the CODE_LIST appears with lot of Left Outer Joins. Need a logic to overcome that difficulty.

Comment: You did say the size was for the DB; but the tables don't seem very big, from the `rows` in the plan output, so I don't see the correlation. Are those accurate or are your stats out of date?

Comment: Out of curiosity wouldn't `ip_STATE.PROPERTY_STRING` be the same as the `MAX (CASE WHEN ip.PROPERTY_TYPE = 'STATE'`. If you do that you could drop the `GROUP BY`. But in any case EVA DB designs tend to have this problem and it requires a lot of work to get to be fast. Usually with indexes and materialized view

Answer (score 1):

can you put an export of the schema on something like drop box or mail it to me at kylelf@gmail.com
With the schema definition we can draw a Visual SQL Tuning (VST) diagram.
Here is a presentation on the method
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ETNcMhRM5s&feature=youtu.be
and slides from the presentation
http://www.slideshare.net/khailey/doag-visual-sql-tuning
A VST and especially a VST with the execution path is much much more powerful than a simple execution plan.